# Executing multicast delegates

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a Multiple target

```
Func<int,int,int> funHandler=Max;
funHandler+=square;
```

When i execute 
`Console.WriteLine(funHandler(10,10));` it return the `square` of 10 (i.e) 200.It did not fire `Max`.

i used something like

```
foreach(var v in funHandler.GetInvocationList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(v(10,20));
}
```

'V' is a variable,but it is used  like a method.How can i fire all methods that is in delegate's
invocation list?

Comment: It does run Max.  Its return value falls in the bit bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, may be `Max` has no side effects and you can't notice it? When you execute multicast delegate it returns result of only last delegate.

Try this:

```
Func<int, int, int> funHandler = (x, y) => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x; };
funHandler += (x, y) => { Console.WriteLine(y); return y; };
int res = funHandler(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See? it works

To use invocation list do this:

```
foreach (var v in funHandler.GetInvocationList())
{
    ((Func<int, int, int>)v)(1, 2);
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (Func<int, int, int> v in funHandler.GetInvocationList())
{
    v(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `foreach (Func<int, int, int> v in funHandler.GetInvocationList()) { v(1,2); }` work as well? Looks cleaner IMHO.

Comment: I think it would work. But I don't like hiding an explicit cast in foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Multicast with a delegate that returns something doesn't make much sense to me. I'd guess it executes all of them but discards all results but one.